# How can I skip a subfigure caption

Tags: subfloats

[image: Subfigures]

i suppressed the caption for the first subfigures so the rest of figures are starting with subsequent label ((b), (c), (d), (e). I want the order as  (a), (b) (c), (d)

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \setlength\figureheight{4cm}
    \setlength\figurewidth{5cm}
\subfigure{
  \includegraphics{legendbr.png}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\subfigure[S]{
  \input{SNM.tikz}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\subfigure[S]{
  \input{SM.tikz}
\label{fig:subfig2}}
\subfigure[S]{
  \input{SD.tikz}
\label{fig:subfig2}}
\subfigure[S]{
  \input{SSep.tikz}
\label{fig:subfig2}}
\caption{In adversary.\label{IN}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `\setcounter{subfloatfigure}{0}` right before the place where the figures should get a caption as (a),(b),etc. This is not optimal, but a workaround.

Comment: repeating your `\label`s is unlikely to help though.

Comment: @user50229: Since it is rather `subfig` used, forget my statement about `\setcounter` above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of `\subfigure` and the corresponding package is discouraged and the support **deprecated**. Please use `subfig` instead. I had to change the `\subfigure` commands to `\subfloat`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{%
\includegraphics[width=80pt,height=50pt]{}%
% \includegraphics{legendbr.png}
\label{fig:subfig1}%
} \par%
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}%
\subfloat[S][]{%
\includegraphics[width=80pt,height=50pt]{}%
% \input{SNM.tikz}
\label{fig:subfig2a}
}%
\subfloat[S][]{%
\includegraphics[width=80pt,height=50pt]{}%
% \input{SM.tikz}
\label{fig:subfig2b}
}%
\par%
\subfloat[][]{%
\includegraphics[width=80pt,height=50pt]{}%
% \input{SD.tikz}
\label{fig:subfig2c}
}%
\subfloat[][]{%
\includegraphics[width=80pt,height=50pt]{}%
%\input{SSep.tikz}
\label{fig:subfig2d}
}%
\par%
\caption{In adversary.\label{IN}}%
\end{figure}%


\end{document}
```

I also changed the labels.

[image]

Comment: Just don't use a `\subfloat` for the legend. This also allows you to remove the `\setcounter` requirement.

Comment: Gotta include `\usepackage{float}` package if you get this error `!LaTeX Error: Unknown float option H'.` while running above code :-P

Comment: @Khaaba: `subfig` loads` `caption`, which loads `float`

Comment: I am using `TeX Live Utility [Version 1.24 (1.24)]` to update my MacTex and it's up to date. While running the code provided by you above on pdfLaTeX via TeXWorks, I still get the error but it resolves when I include `float` package

Comment: @Khaaba: You're right. Apparently there's been some change in packages since I've posted this

Comment: Possible! I saw many changes in last one year :-D. In some situations, my own codes [teaching notes] which worked last year do not work at present... there have been instructions to change order of packages too, for example, `tikz` before `booktab`... few things I learned how to tackle but in few cases, I could not even run the code provided as answers with output... they don't work at all. Changes are good to avoid redundancies, to reduce memory etc :-D

Comment: @Khaaba: Thanks for sending me a note. I've just removed '[H]' -- that's the shortest edit ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to clean your folder. You should have .aux, .log, .toc and some other file with your .tex file. They are used to compile your file and in particular, make all label.

If you erase all file (except your .tex of course) it'll work.

Comment: Running Tex/LaTeX (whatever) twice should do the same without deleting files (apart from some toc issues).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know but I think He already done this in fact.

Comment: I am not sure if `subfloat` is used at all, but I think, resetting the `subfloatfigure` counter will do also.